# Stop playing HTML5Media when jQuery UI tab is switched

Tags: jquery, html, video, tabs

Is it possible to stop an HTML5 video from playing when the tab is switched or out of focus?

I am using [HTML5 video](http://html5media.info/) in conjunction with [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

I apologize in advance, I can't seem to find a working solution.

---

Thanks for your help, but my knowledge of javascript is at amateur level. I tried using CSS to throw it off screen instead of hiding it, but that didn't work either.

WTK, Thanks, your solution worked for every browser but IE 7/8. IE kicks back an error ("Object doesn't support this property or method") and won't switch to the video tab at all – it's broken in IE.

I assume that's because IE < v.9 doesn't understand the html5 video object and falls back to Flowplayer when using HTML5Media's solution…?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // if tab we're switching to isn't the one with a video player
        if (ui.tab.id != 'tab_with_player') {
            // pause your video player
            $("#your_video_tag")[0].pause();
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

handling the [select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) should do the trick.